# Sequelize model to SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a project which uses sequelize to communicate with part of a database. The project should not have the responsibility to update the database structure so no sequelize syncing or migrations are being used.
I got asked to find a way to still be able to generate the database from the sequelize models. The ideia is to be able to update models and run a command that generates an SQL with the necessary queries to create the tables, based on the sequelize models. Not even asking for migrations, only the table creation.
Any solution?

Comment: Do you keep in mind that table creation also involves indexes, primary keys, foreign keys? Basically you wish to do the same as `model.sync()` does but manually. Are you sure you want to do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.